RISCV Pipeline Register after Instruction Fetch
In a pipelined RISC-V CPU, given that IMEM is synchronous read. Why do we setup the PC and instruction registers in the following way?
Overall RISC-V Implementation
From what I know this is data flow after PC is set initially:
Data Flow after PC
This would result in a mismatch between the PC register and instruction register in the following stage. However, every reference I see is set up like this.

I think you are wrong in your understanding of a data flow. Entirety of instruction fetch happens in a single cycle. PC register settles, IMEM read happens and the instruction latch locks the read instruction - all of that happens in a single cycle 1. So latches between IF and ID hold PC of the instruction read during IF, and that instruction.

Your question is not entirely clear, but I believe that you assume that loading data from the instruction memory only happens on the rising edge of the clock. This is not entirely the case, usually there is some cache which will read async so that the data becomes available within one cycle. If the read has to come from a memory that only reads on the rising edge of the clock, a stall cycle needs to be induced, which freezes the entire cpu in place so that the memory has time to catch up to the pipeline.
